# Unable to re-construct a file using byte array retrieved from another file (chunk-by-chunk)

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am currently trying to construct file B by extracting a certain length of bytes from file A (chunk-by-chunk). The size of file B is 38052441 bytes, and its location in file A is from byte 34 onward. If I do it in one shot, I manage to extract file B from file A without any issue, as shown in the snippet below.

```
 test = new byte[38052441];
 //madefilePath: file A, madecabfilePath: file B
 using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(madefilePath, FileMode.Open)))
 using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(madecabfilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
 {
     reader.BaseStream.Seek(34, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     reader.Read(test, 0, 38052441);

     bw.Write(test);
     bw.Close();
     reader.Close();
 }
```

Howerver, if I try to do it in multiple query (I have to do this, because this feature will be ported to compact framework in the future), I kept on getting a corrupted file. Currently, I am testing by getting the first 20Mb, write into a file, then get the remaining bytes and write it into the file again.

```
int max = 38052474;
int offset = 34;
int weight = 20000000;
bool isComplete = false;
test = null;
test = new byte[weight];

using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(madecabfilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(madefilePath, FileMode.Open)))
{
            while (!isComplete)
            {
                if (offset + weight < max)
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    reader.Read(test, 0, weight);
                    bw.Write(test);
                    offset = offset + weight;
                }
                else
                {
                    weight = max - offset;
                    test = null;
                    test = new byte[weight];
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    reader.Read(test, 0, weight);
                    bw.Write(test);

                    //Terminate everything
                    reader.Close();
                    bw.Close();
                    isComplete = true;
                }
            }
 }
```

I think the issue lies with my logic, but I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code makes use of many _magic numbers_ instead of using the actual size of the file

Comment: Have you used a hex editor and ran a diff to see what is corrupt? I'm guessing it just may be a length issue.

Comment: Currently I only want to get the routine working, the above code will be refined. I have found out the issue though, it is on the following line: weight = max - offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryReader.Read()` returns the number of bytes that were actually read.  So you can simplify your logic and probably fix some issues with something like:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(madecabfilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(madefilePath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while (!isComplete)
    {
        int charsRead = reader.Read(test, 0, weight);
        if (charsRead == 0)
        {
            isComplete = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bw.Write(test, 0, charsRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly close `bw` or `reader`, as the `using` statement will do that for you.  Also note that after the first `Seek()` call the position in the `BinaryReader` will be kept track of.

Comment: A good one indeed. I didn't know BinaryReader keeps track of the position  on the stream. Although I have found out about the issue on my routine, but I will try to implement your answer, thank you. I consider this as solved.